# Is there any possible way to retrieve an ArrayList value from an OnCllickListener method and save it in it's parent method?

Tags: java, android, function, methods

```
 saveBtnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    saveBtnYesFunc(currentYesBtnId);
                    tempActivityList =activityNames;
                    return activityNames;
                }
            });
```

When I call the `saveBtnYesFunc` function, it returns an ArrayList value called `activityNames` to the onClick thread. I want to pass that value from inside of the `onClickListener` method to its parent method (this code is contained within another method). The last line of code `return activityNames` won't work.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: That "parent method" may not be executing by the time the click listener is executed. You're saying "Call this code whenever the button is clicked"... which could be never, or it could be after the method has completed. I think you need to rethink your UI, in terms of a more event-oriented approach.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have been deep in the problem that I didn't notice that, thanks for shedding light on it. The problem is that there is an AutoCompleteTextView in the onCreate function that I need to set its adapter using that list which is saved using SharedPrefrences. The problem is that the contents of the list are set in the **saveBtnYesFunc** method, and I need to get those values somehow so I can use them in the onCreate method. If you need more information on how those parts should work, please tell me. I will do my best to explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to determine who is actually interested in seeing this new list.  Assuming that the interested part is an instance of some class ListUsingClass, this should work.

```
final ListUsingClass listUser = new ListUsingClass(); // or assign to existing reference
saveBtnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listUser.setActivityNames(saveBtnYesFunc(currentYesBtnId));
                 }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear, I think you want that when a `Button` is clicked, an `Array` (`activityNames`) is saved somewhere.
You can do this in this way, if I understood well:

```
class YourClass {  //almost surely it extends Activity (or AppCompatActivity)

    private List<String> thePlaceWhereTheArrayWillBeLocated = new ArrayList<String>();  //You should define a class varibale where the result of saveBtnYesFunc will ends up (I think that the content is of String type)

    ... onCreate(...) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ...
    saveBtnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   //I don't know if it's inside the onCreate, but it could be here
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                thePlaceWhereTheArrayWillBeLocated = saveBtnYesFunc(currentYesBtnId);  //Maybe some type casts are needed
                //tempActivityList =activityNames;
                //return activityNames;    //This line is totally incorrect
            }
        });
    }

    void wheneverFunctionYouWant() {
        //do whatever you want with thePlaceWhereTheArrayWillBeLocated 
    }
}
```